# Figure recognition in 2d array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-recognition

I want to recognize 2d figures (for example tetris figures where 1 means filled block and 0 means empty plane) in 2d array (seeded randomly with 0 and 1). Are there any general approaches? First idea is to iterate over source array assuming that A[i,j] is origin point of expected figure and to compare derived figure with the reference one.

For 100x100 array and 10x10 figures this will take  (100-10)*(100-10)=8100 operations, and this means O=n^2 in general because there can be many figures am I correct? Of course caching can be applied, and we can try to iterate only over "dirty" sections...

However I suppose better solutions should exist. Can someone point them out?

Comment: How important is performance in this situation? Make it work, Make it right, and, if needed, Make it fast. Create something that builds and does what you want and see if the performance really matters.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach I would take would be O(n^2) as well, but would seem to scale more on the number of figures (polyominoes) than in the number of blocks.

Iterate over each block, if it is set (ie: its value is 1), look at its 4 connecting neighbor grid cells. From this (and any other connecting neighbor cells), you should be able to determine what shape it is, and you can mark those cells as observed, so you can skip them when you iterate to them. This way you would look at each cell in turn, but most of the code only executes when you're actively looking for a tromino in a cell.

I suppose it matters greatly whether the number of figures in the grid is known ahead of time or not.